# C print hex bytes

Tags: c, printing, printf

I have code in a C program with hex data which I want to iterate over, for example to print out each of the hex bytes:

```
char input[] = "\x31\xd2\xb2\x30";
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
    printf("%02X\n", input[i]);
}
```

However, the output is not what I expect, for example the above prints:

```
31
FFFFFFD2
FFFFFFB2
30
```

I also tried to cast the output as an `(unsigned int)`, however I receive the same output.

Can somebody point out the issue with this simple script?

Comment: On your system, `char` is probably `signed`. So the data `\xd2` is negative. You pass that value to `printf` and it gets promoted to `int` which is also signed. But the format specifier `%X` is expecting an `unsigned int` and interprets the binary data accordingly. It is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments passed to printf are sign extended unless you cast them to an unsigned type like this:

```
printf("%02X\n", (unsigned char)input[i]);
```

Comment: Oops you're right. I used an unsigned int, but of course it's a char.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%02X")` expects an unsigned integer; Passing a negative value of type `char` (and `0xD2` of type `char` is a negative value) will lead to promote the negative char value to a 32 bit unsigned int, thereby filling up the leading bits with `1` and yielding `0xFFFFFFD2`in the end. This is then printed.

To overcome this, you could "tell" `printf` to take the value provided as an 8 bit value:

```
printf("%02hhX\n", input[i])
```

Another option would be to declare `input` as `unsigned char`, because then `0xD2` would not be considered "negative", and promotion to 32 bit would work as expected:

```
unsigned char input[] = "\x31\xd2\xb2\x30";
```

Note that then `strlen` would require to cast the input, i.e. `strlen((char*)intput)`.

Answer (score 0):

`char input[]` must be `unsigned char input[]`. That's how you store binary bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can use like this  

char input[] = "\x31\xd2\xb2\x30";

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {  
    printf("%02X\n", input[i] & 0xff);  
}  

Output: 
31  
D2  
B2  
30
```

it will mask out the upper bits and keep only the lower 8 bits.